# Replace text on which comment scope spans (Word)

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-automation

I have a Word document, with comments

[image: Ms Word Document with comments]

I want to programmatically replace a text that is subject to a comment:

```
Sub ReplaceTextOfComments()
    For Each c In ActiveDocument.Comments
        If c.Range.Text = "BAR" Then
            c.Scope.Text = "H"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

The result I get is the following:

[image: Ms Word Document with comments]

Is there any way to preserve the scope of the comment while replacing the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could figure out is to create a new comment around the new text, deleting the previous comment. I did try changing the `Start` property of the Comment.Scope, but that doesn't appear to have any effect.

The following code works. What threw me off for quite a while is the fact that Word apparently does not honor a Comment object. If I set a Comment to a variable, then insert a new comment, and the new comment is inserted/indexed before the original, then the new one replaces the original in the object variable. So, in the code below, cmtOrig actually contains the Comment just added, not the original. So doing cmtOrig.Delete actually deletes cmtNew, with the result that the remaining Comment doesn't contain the target Range. But it does appear to work reliably using the Index.

The one caveat, though, is that you lose any formatting in the Comment.

```
Sub ReplaceCommentRangeText()
    Dim rngCommentScope As word.Range
    Dim cmtOrig As word.Comment, cmtNew As Comment
    Dim cmtIndex As Long
    Dim rngTarget As word.Range

    Set cmtOrig = ActiveDocument.Comments(1)
    cmtIndex = cmtOrig.index
    Set rngCommentScope = cmtOrig.Scope
    rngCommentScope.Text = "C"
    Set cmtNew = ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(rngCommentScope, cmtOrig.Range.Text)
    'Debug.Print cmtNew.index, cmtIndex
    If cmtNew.index = cmtIndex Then
        ActiveDocument.Comments(cmtIndex + 1).Delete
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Comments(cmtIndex).Delete
    End If
End Sub
```